# How to have same alignment of DIV's in an iFrame?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Trying to iframe a section of website (http://edmontontrafficcam.com) i.e. the Map & Video div..

My code for Iframe is customized through CSS to contain the Map & Video Div. But while loading the iframe, the video comes below the map and is not visible. I want the exact view that of the website, where the video is aligned at the right,without scrolling bars.

Clicking on the map, I lose focus to video, after which i need to reload the website to get map view.

```
<div 
style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; width: 1800px;"  > 
<iframe src="http://edmontontrafficcam.com/" style="
border: 0px none; 
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: -200px;
margin-right: -900px; 
height: 850px;  
width: 850px;"> 
</iframe> 
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to keep the div aligned as per seen in the website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my HTMl, the following code has given the result I believe you want. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Code:

```
<div 
  style="
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 1800px;
  "> 
  <iframe src="http://edmontontrafficcam.com/" 
  style="
    border: 0px none; 
    margin-left: -1000px;
    margin-top: -220px;
    margin-right: -900px; 
    height: 900px;  
    width: 1400px;
  "> 
  </iframe> 
</div>
```

Comment: This looks very close to what i require, now I have the 2 Divs aligned together. But I need to disable the auto-scrolling where the footer is visible. Tried with scrolling="no" parameter, but somehow it slides down to the footer once clicked

Comment: Also just noticed the height of the iframe is a little too small, so you might want to change it to '900px' instead, edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: Oops, didn't read your comment properly, let me have a play and try and fix this.

Comment: Can't figure out a way to not have the footer without it scrolling when you click on a camera unfortunatey.

You can however just display the footer in the first place, so when you click on the map it doesn't need to scroll. To do this simply change the height value to the following `height: 968px;`

Comment: Played around with margin-bottom, so it doesnt scroll till the footer now. The current width & height was the issue,

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the `width` of your iframe to match to the parent `div`(preferably above 992px) as the behaviour which you mentioned ('I lose focus to video') is part of the actual website. You could find the same if you shrink the page there.

```
<div> 
  <iframe src="http://edmontontrafficcam.com" 
          style="border: 0px none;
                 width: 1000px;
                 height: 900px;
                 margin-left: 20px;
                 margin-top: -200px;
                 margin-right: -900px;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I did worked when width was properly set. Thank You

Comment: @AliHabib - Glad to know that it helped. You may upvote and mark the correct answer to help the other users easily find the right solution to similar queries.